# Azure Pipelines 'Cache' task cannot find package-lock.json

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to cache my npm packages in our build Azure DevOps build pipeline (YAML), to reduce the time it takes to run the pipeline. But after adding the `Cache@2` task (full code later) the build pipeline fails with the following output from the cache task:

```
Starting: Cache npm
==============================================================================
Task         : Cache
Description  : Cache files between runs
Version      : 2.198.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/pipeline-caching-docs
==============================================================================
Resolving key:
 - npm               [string]
 - "Linux"           [string]
 - package-lock.json [file] (not found)
##[error]One or several exceptions have been occurred.
##[error]System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File not found: package-lock.json
Finishing: Cache npm
```

I have followed the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#nodejsnpm) and added the following code in the beginning of the YAML file:

```
variables:
  npmCacheDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm/

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'
    restoreKeys: |
       npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
    path: $(npm_config_cache)
  displayName: Cache npm

- script: npm ci
```

I have tried adjusting the `path` variable, as I cannot figure out if it is supposed to point to where the `package-lock.json` file is located. My app is made with the [dotnet React template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio), so the `package-lock.json` file is located in `./src/MyApp/ClientApp/` directory. Albeit, the solution file is also in the `./src/` directory, if you need to know the relative location to that.

What am I doing wrong here? I have even tried to consult ChatGPT, without any luck :p

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, and the solution that is working for me is to add steps to checkout the repo (and to set your node version if applicable) prior to running the cache step:

```
variables:
  NPM_CONFIG_CACHE: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm

steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: true
    clean: true
    displayName: 'Checkout'

  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: 'Set Node.js version to v18.x'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '18.x'

  - task: Cache@2
    displayName: 'Cache npm'
    inputs:
      key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'
      path: $(NPM_CONFIG_CACHE)
      restoreKeys: |
        npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have package-lock.json file already in place but your agent can not locate the right path for it, you may add working directory in yaml file and pass the right file location:

```
steps:
- script: |

echo 'y' | npm run deploy:cicd
   
  **workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_zui5azuregitproj1'**
.....
```